# complex table join in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to update target table column brand code using source table column Brand_code based on the long_item_number and chain

but long_item_number in source contain hyphen where as Target table long item is not having hypen

Chain CM in source is equivalent to 7 in target, similarly EPRC equivalent to 1, FSC equivalent to 3.

sample data:

```
DECLARE  @SRC_SOURCE TABLE
(
Chain varchar (10),
Long_item_number varchar (100),
product_name varchar (500),
Brand_code varchar(500)
)
INSERT @SRC_SOURCE
SELECT 'CM',    '30041000300254600000', 'Hynix',    'Samsung COLLECTION' UNION ALL
SELECT 'EPRC',  '35510100000090000000', 'cd-100',   'Samsung COLLECTION' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FSC',   '00610010000010000024', 'KNIT', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FSC',   '01530060040250000000', '4025-31',  '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FSC',   '01530060040100000000', '4010-31',  '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FSC',   '01530060040120000000', '4012-31',  NULL 
--SELECT * FROM @SRC_SOURCE
DECLARE  @TGT_TARGET TABLE
(
Chain INT,
Long_item_number varchar (100),
product_name varchar (500),
Brand_code varchar(500)
)
INSERT @TGT_TARGET
SELECT 7,   '3004-10003-0025-460-0000', '7.5. Score', 'Samsung  Galaxy' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   '3551-01000-0009-000-0000', '7.5. Score', 'Samsung  Galaxy' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '0061-00100-0001-000-0024', '8.3. Score', 'Samsung  jbl' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '0153-00600-4025-000-0000', '8.3. Score', 'Samsung  Ultra' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '0153-00600-4010-000-0000', '8.3. Score', 'Samsung  Ultra' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '0153-00600-4012-000-0000', '7.5. Score', 'Samsung  flip3'
SELECT * FROM @TGT_TARGET
```

Code I tried.

```
update t
set t.brand_code = s.brand_code
from source s
    inner join target t on
       s.long_item_number = t.long_item_number
and s.chain = t.chain
```

Can Any one please help me how to use **case** in join condition for Chain and how to take care of **hyphen** in key column long_item_id in target for join condition.

Comment: Does REPLACE() in the join on clause solve your issue?  s.long_item_number = replace(t.long_item_number,'-','')